# Obeying react-hooks/exhaustive-deps leads to infinite loops and/or lots of useCallback()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My app has a `userService` that exposes a `useUserService` hook with API functions such as `getUser`, `getUsers`, etc. I use a Hook for this because the API calls require information from my Session state, which is provided by a React Context Provider.

Providing the `getUsers` functions to a `useEffect` call makes the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` eslint rule unhappy, because it wants the `getUsers` function listed as a dep - however, listing it as a dep causes the effect to run in an infinite loop, because each time the component is re-rendered, it re-runs the `useUserService` hook, which recreates the `getUsers` function.

This can be remedied by wrapping the functions in `useCallback`, but then the `useCallback` dependency array runs into a similar lint rule. I figure I must be doing something wrong here, because I can't imagine I'm supposed to wrap every single one of these functions in `useCallback()`.

I've recreated the issue in Codesandbox.

1: Encounter `eslint` warning: https://codesandbox.io/s/usecallback-lint-part-1-76bcf?file=/src/useFetch.ts

2: Remedy `eslint` warning by sprinkling `useCallback` in, leading to another `eslint` warning: https://codesandbox.io/s/usecallback-lint-part-2-uwhhf?file=/src/App.js

3: Remedy *that* `eslint` rule by going deeper: https://codesandbox.io/s/usecallback-lint-part-3-6wfwj?file=/src/apiService.ts

Everything works completely fine if I just ignore the lint warning... but should I?

Comment: Disabling the rule for functions will 100% lead to bugs as soon as you read from props or state somewhere "on the way" as you pass functions down. See my response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to keep the exact API and constraints you've already chosen, **that *is* the canonical solution** — you need to ensure that everything "all the way down" has `useCallback` or `useMemo` around it.

So this is unfortunately correct:

> I can't imagine I'm supposed to wrap every single one of these functions in useCallback()

There is a concrete practical reason for it. If something at the very bottom of the chain changes (in your example, it would be the "session state from React's context" you're referring to), you somehow need this change to propagate to the effects. Since otherwise they'd keep using stale context.

However, **my general suggestion would be to try to avoid building APIs like this in the first place**. In particular, building an API like `useFetch` that takes an arbitrary function as a callback, and then calling it in effect, poses all sorts of questions. Like what do you *want* to happen if that function closes over some state that changes? What if the consumer passes an inline function that's always "different"? If you only respected the initial function, would you be OK with the code being buggy when you're getting `cond ? fn1 : fn2` as an argument?

So, generally speaking, I would strongly discourage building a helper like this, and instead rethink the API so that you don't need to inject a "way to fetch" into a data fetching function, and instead that data fetching function knows *how* to fetch by itself.

TLDR: a custom Hook taking a function that is then needed inside of an effect is often unnecessarily generic and leads to complications like this.

---

For a concrete example of how you could write this differently:

1. First, write down your API functions at top level. Not as Hooks — just plain top-level functions. Whatever they need (including "session context") should be in their arguments.

```
// api.js

export function fetchUser(session, userId) {
  return axios(...)
}
```

2. Create Hooks to get any data they need from the Context.

```
function useSession() {
  return useContext(Session)
}
```

3. Compose these things together.

```
function useFetch(callApi) {
  const session = useSession()
  useEffect(() => {
    callApi(session).then(...)
    // ...
  }, [callApi, session])
}
```

And

```
import * as api from './api'

function MyComponent() {
  const data = useFetch(api.fetchUser)
}
```

Here, `api.fetchUser` never "changes" so you don't have any `useCallback` at all.

Edit: I realized I skipped passing the arguments through, like `userId`. You could add an `args` array to `useFetch` that only takes serializable values, and use `JSON.stringify(args)` in your dependencies. You'd still have to disable the rule but crucially **you're complying with the spirit of the rule — dependencies are specified**. Which is pretty different from disabling it for functions, which leads to subtle bugs.

Comment: I added an example of how you could restructure this to pass a "bare" function to `useEffect`, which wouldn't matter even if it was in dependencies (because it never changes).