# eslint warning for missing dependency in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am making a searchable Dropdown and getting following eslint warning:

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'filterDropDown' and 'restoreDropDown'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
const SearchableDropDown2 = () => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  const [dropdownOptions, setDropdownOptions] = useState([
    "React",
    "Angular",
    "Vue",
    "jQuery",
    "Nextjs",
  ]);
  const [copyOfdropdownOptions, setCopyOfDropdownOptions] = useState([
    ...dropdownOptions,
  ]);
  const [isExpand, setIsExpand] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    searchText.length > 0 ? filterDropDown() : restoreDropDown();
  }, [searchText]);

  const onClickHandler = (e) => {
    setSearchText(e.target.dataset.myoptions);
    setIsExpand(false);
  };

  const onSearchDropDown = () => setIsExpand(true);

  const closeDropDownHandler = () => setIsExpand(false);

  const filterDropDown = useCallback(() => {
    const filteredDropdown = dropdownOptions.filter((_) =>
      _.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
    );
    setDropdownOptions([...filteredDropdown]);
  }, [dropdownOptions]);

  const restoreDropDown = () => {
    if (dropdownOptions.length !== copyOfdropdownOptions.length) {
      setDropdownOptions([...copyOfdropdownOptions]);
    }
  };

  const onSearchHandler = (e) => setSearchText(e.target.value.trim());
  return (
    <div style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <input
        type="search"
        value={searchText}
        onClick={onSearchDropDown}
        onChange={onSearchHandler}
        style={styles.search}
        placeholder="search"
      />
      <button disabled={!isExpand} onClick={closeDropDownHandler}>
        -
      </button>
      <div
        style={
          isExpand
            ? styles.dropdownContainer
            : {
                ...styles.dropdownContainer,
                height: "0vh",
              }
        }
      >
        {dropdownOptions.map((_, idx) => (
          <span
            onClick={onClickHandler}
            style={styles.dropdownOptions}
            data-myoptions={_}
            value={_}
          >
            {_}
          </span>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const styles = {
  mainContainer: {
    padding: "1vh 1vw",
    width: "28vw",
    margin: "auto auto",
  },
  dropdownContainer: {
    width: "25vw",
    background: "grey",
    height: "10vh",
    overflow: "scroll",
  },
  dropdownOptions: {
    display: "block",
    height: "2vh",
    color: "white",
    padding: "0.2vh 0.5vw",
    cursor: "pointer",
  },
  search: {
    width: "25vw",
  },
};
```

I tried wrapping the `filterDropDown` in `useCallback` but then the searchable dropdown stopped working.

Following are the changes incorporating `useCallback`:

```
const filterDropDown = useCallback(() => {
  const filteredDropdown = dropdownOptions.filter((_) =>
    _.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
  );
  setDropdownOptions([...filteredDropdown]);
}, [dropdownOptions, searchText]);
```

Comment: Similar [Obeying react-hooks/exhaustive-deps leads to infinite loops and/or lots of useCallback()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66537226/2873538)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to not use `useEffect` at all in the context of what you are achieving.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const SearchableDropDown = () => {
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
    const dropdownOptions = ['React','Angular','Vue','jQuery','Nextjs'];
    const [isExpand, setIsExpand] = useState(false);


    const onClickHandler = e =>  {
        setSearchText(e.target.dataset.myoptions);
        setIsExpand(false);
    }

    const onSearchDropDown = () => setIsExpand(true);
    const closeDropDownHandler = () => setIsExpand(false);
    const onSearchHandler = e => setSearchText(e.target.value.trim());

    return (
        <div style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <input
                type="search"
                value={searchText}
                onClick={onSearchDropDown}
                onChange={onSearchHandler}
                style={styles.search}
                placeholder="search"
            />
            <button disabled={!isExpand} onClick={closeDropDownHandler}>
                -
            </button>
            <div
                style={
                    isExpand
                        ? styles.dropdownContainer
                        : {
                                ...styles.dropdownContainer,
                                height: '0vh',
                            }
                }
            >
                {dropdownOptions
                    .filter(opt => opt.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
                    .map((option, idx) =>
                        <span key={idx} onClick={onClickHandler} style={styles.dropdownOptions} data-myoptions={option} value={option}>
                            {option}
                        </span>
                    )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const styles = {
    mainContainer: {
        padding: '1vh 1vw',
        width: '28vw',
        margin: 'auto auto'
    },
    dropdownContainer: {
        width: '25vw',
        background: 'grey',
        height: '10vh',
        overflow: 'scroll'
    },
    dropdownOptions: {
        display: 'block',
        height: '2vh',
        color: 'white',
        padding: '0.2vh 0.5vw',
        cursor: 'pointer',
    },
    search: {
        width: '25vw',
    },
};
```

Just filter the `dropDownOptions` before mapping them to the `span` elements.

also, if the list of `dropDownOptions` is ever going to change then use `setState` else just leave it as a simple list. If `dropDownOptions` comes from an api call, then use `setState` within the `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code:

```
// 1. Filter

const filterDropDown = useCallback(() => {
  const filteredDropdown = dropdownOptions.filter((_) =>
    _.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
  );
  setDropdownOptions([...filteredDropdown]);
}, [dropdownOptions]);

// 2. Restore

const restoreDropDown = () => {
  if (dropdownOptions.length !== copyOfdropdownOptions.length) {
    setDropdownOptions([...copyOfdropdownOptions]);
  }
};

// 3. searchText change effect

useEffect(() => {
  searchText.length > 0 ? filterDropDown() : restoreDropDown();
}, [searchText]);
```

Above code produces [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) warning that:

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'filterDropDown' and 'restoreDropDown'. Either include them or remove the dependency array

**BUT** after doing what the warning says, our code finally looks like:

```
// 1. Filter

const filterDropDown = useCallback(() => {
  const filteredDropdown = dropdownOptions.filter((_) =>
    _.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
  );
  setDropdownOptions(filteredDropdown);
}, [dropdownOptions, searchText]);

// 2. Restore

const restoreDropDown = useCallback(() => {
  if (dropdownOptions.length !== copyOfdropdownOptions.length) {
    setDropdownOptions([...copyOfdropdownOptions]);
  }
}, [copyOfdropdownOptions, dropdownOptions.length]);

// 3. searchText change effect

useEffect(() => {
  searchText.length > 0 ? filterDropDown() : restoreDropDown();
}, [filterDropDown, restoreDropDown, searchText]);
```

But the above code has formed an **infinite** loop because:

1. "Filter" function is OK. (It will be recreated when `searchText` or `dropdownOptions` change. And that makes sense.)
2. "Restore" function is OK. (It will be recreated when `copyOfdropdownOptions` or `dropdownOptions.length` change. And this too makes sense.)
3. `searchText` change effect looks **bad**. This effect will run whenever:

   => (a).  `searchText` is changed (OK), or
   => (b).  "Filter" function is changed (*Not OK* because this function itself will change when this hook is run. Point 1), or
   => (c).  "Restore" function is changed (*Not OK* because this function itself will change when this hook is run. Point 2)

We can clearly see an *infinite* loop in Point 3 (a, b, c).

#### How to fix it?

There can be few ways. One could be:

The below *copy* is constant, so either keep it in a Ref or move it outside the component definition:

```
const copyOfdropdownOptions = useRef([...dropdownOptions]);
```

And, *move* the "Filter" and "Restore" functions inside the hook (i.e. no need to define it outside and put it as a dependency), like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (searchText.length) {
    // 1. Filter
    setDropdownOptions((prev) =>
      prev.filter((_) => _.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
    );
  } else {
    // 2. Restore
    setDropdownOptions([...copyOfdropdownOptions.current]);
  }
}, [searchText]);
```

As you can see the above effect will run only when `searchText` is changed.

Comment: Oop! I see a **bug**:  We need to always *filter* on original data: `setDropdownOptions(copyOfdropdownOptions.current.filter((_) => _.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))`