# React useMemo missing dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const handleTestDelete = (id: any) => {
    deleteTest(id).then(() => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries("test");
    });
  };

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 80 },
      {
        field: "",
        width: 120,
        disableClickEventBubbling: true,
        sortable: false,
        disableColumnMenu: true,
        renderCell: (cell: any) => (
          <>
            <IconButton
              aria-label="delete"
              onClick={() => handleTestDelete(cell.id)}
            >
              <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              aria-label="view"
              onClick={() => history.push(`/something/${cell.id}/details`)}
            >
              <VisibilityIcon fontSize="small" />
            </IconButton>
          </>
        ),
      },
    ],
    [history]
```

I am getting this warning

> React Hook useMemo has a missing dependency: 'handleTestDelete'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

because I am not adding the function called on click of the delete button in dependencies ... why should I put it as a dependency? I'm not even sure if putting history as a dependency is correct; I don't think columns need to be reevaluated when chronology changes

I was wrong?

Thank you

Comment: thanks, removed the image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `useMemo`, you should satisfy its dependencies as the suggested by [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks):

```
const history = useHistory()

const columns = useMemo(() => {
  console.log("define memoized columns") // Log 1
  return [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 80 },
    {
      // ... code here
      renderCell: (cell: any) => (
        <>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="delete"
            onClick={() => handleTestDelete(cell.id)}
          >
            <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="view"
            onClick={() => history.push(`/something/${cell.id}/details`)}
          >
            <VisibilityIcon fontSize="small" />
          </IconButton>
        </>
      ),
    },
  ]
}, [history, handleTestDelete])
```

Using `history` would be safe because it won't change (unless it is changed in React Router's context which is unlikely in this example). And, you would need to wrap that function in a `useCallback`:

```
const handleTestDelete = useCallback((id: any) => {
  deleteTest(id).then(() => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries('test')
  })
}, []) // <---- Here, you need to add the dependencies as well (maybe queryClient)
```

You may have one more option here: Remove `handleTestDelete` from the `useMemo`'s dependencies and define the `handleTestDelete` function inside the `useMemo`; before returning the memoized columns.

Note: As I don't see your complete code, I would suggest that you test this code and make sure that the *Log 1* in `useMemo` is printed appropriately (only once).

---

Similar posts:

- [eslint warning for missing dependency in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67026861/2873538)
- [Obeying react-hooks/exhaustive-deps leads to infinite loops and/or
  lots of useCallback()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66537226/2873538)

Comment: can i check useCallback evaluations as you did in useMemo ?

Comment: Do you mean - writing a log like `console.log("recreating function handleTestDelete")`?  Yes. I would test that as well. I guess that ESLINT would be complaining about a missing dependency of `queryClient` (perhaps, it comes from react-query's context) only.

Comment: yes, but how can i log it? can you paste here some code? thanks

Comment: Something like: `const handleTestDelete = useCallback((id: any) => { console.log("recreating function handleTestDelete"); deleteTest(id).then(() => { queryClient.invalidateQueries('test') }) }, [])`

Comment: mmm no, this will be logged on function call...useCallback take the function to memoize as param, so don't know if i can log the useCallback evaluation :(

Comment: Yes, i understand now. Use `useEffect(() => { console.log("function handleTestDelete is changed or recreated"); }, [handleTestDelete])` to see a log whenever the function is recreated. You need to make sure that it is not recreated unnecessarily.

Comment: yes that could be a good workaround for check renders. thanks